# Sum of X digits in an array equals a digit in Y array

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sum

I have this algorithm problem. I have two arrays.

```
$arrDetail = array(1,4,8,2,12,10); 
$arrSum = array(9,10,18);
```

*condition* - sum(arrDetail) = sum(arrSum)

how can I write algorithm to create all combinations of the arrDetail and then match them to the arrSum?

the result would like this:

```
1 + 8 = 9
4 + 2 + 12 = 18
10 = 10
```

I have tried creating all combinations of *arrDetail* and then match them in a loop to the *arrSum*, but it does not work with larger arrays. Also, I'm looking for a first valid combinations.

Comment: is this your homework assignment？

Comment: This is known as the [subset sum problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem). You're just solving the problem for each sum given in the second array.

Comment: Yes, it is a work assignment.

Comment: I have looked at the Subset sum problem, but this one is a little different, because the total sum of the detail items equals the total sum of the summary array. How would you solve it knowing that fact?